# Easily formatting a Pathfinder stat block

Tags: pathfinder-1e, publishing

What procedure can I use so I can enter the statistics for a Pathfinder character or monster, and get some formatted text of a proper stat block? Either to print or to use in software like Microsoft Word or Adobe Indesign.

For example, when I wrote 3.5 adventures I used DM Genie which had a screen where I could enter all the stats. Which filled out a text box. Then I could copy and paste a proper 3.5 stat block into Word or Indesign.

This is an issue that effects several of the more popular RPGs other than Pathfinder. So a good answer would benefit many who struggle to write and share material for these games as the writing of detailed stat blocks is labor intensive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78501/discussion-on-question-by-rs-conley-easily-formatting-a-pathfinder-stat-block).

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "get some formatted text"? What I'm wondering is, are you a) looking for a tool that will take input in YAML or Markdown format, then produce output in a table usable by Microsoft word and/or make a PDF?  OR b) looking for a tool that will take shorthand notes like "dwarf," then go off to Pathfinder data files, then report back details on what the dwarf special abilities like "Hardy" and "Defensive Training" mean?  I think both are interesting questions, but the first does not need the Pathfinder data files in PCGen; the second does.

Answer (score 4):

The free open source software tool [PCGen](http://pcgen.org/) supports creating both Player and Non Player Characters, using many of the available sourcebooks for Pathfinder. After creating the character, a number of different output styles can be created, including the Pathfinder standard style Stat Block - an example of this output produced by the latest version of the tool appears below, converted to plain text. PDF and HTML versions can be produced as well.

The actual procedure for creating a monster or character can be quite involved, depending on the number of options involved, but the tool does its best to flag what needs to be done. Creating standard creature stat blocks is as simple as selecting one option from a list.

Note that PCGen is a volunteer-produced tool, and does not always support the latest sourcebooks, or a complete set of sourcebooks. The datafiles are human-readable, and can be expanded to suit your needs.

I've not had a lot of experience with it, but I gather the commerical tool Herolab can also produce similar output. Herolab does have a non-trivial cost associated with it, and there are charges for each sourcebook used.

> AKATA CR 2
>
> XP 600
>
> Male advanced young akata
>
> N Medium aberration
>
> Init +8; Senses darkvision 60 ft., scent,  Perception +3
>
> DEFENSE
>
> AC 17, touch 14, flat-footed 13 (+4 Dex, +3 natural)
> hp 19 (2d8+10)
> Fort +5, Ref +4, Will +6
>
> Immune cold, disease, poison;   Resist  fire 30
> Weaknesses Deaf, Vulnerable to Salt Water,
>
> OFFENSE
> Speed 40 ft., climb 20 ft.
> Melee bite +4 (1d6+3)
> Melee tentacle -1/-1 (1d3+1)
>
> Special Attacks void bite(bite)
>
> STATISTICS
> Str 16, Dex 19, Con 20, Int 7, Wis 16, Cha 15
> Base Atk +1; CMB +4; CMD 18
>
> Feats Improved Initiative
>
> Skills Acrobatics +8 , Acrobatics (Jump) +12 , Climb +11 , Stealth +8
>
> SQ hibernation, no breath, resistance to fire 30, scent
>
> Gear   bite, tentacle
>
> SPECIAL ABILITIES
>
> Darkvision (Ex)  Range 60 ft.; Darkvision is the extraordinary ability to see with no light source at all, out to a range specified for the creature. Darkvision is black and white only (colors cannot be discerned). It does not allow characters to see anything that they could not see otherwise-invisible objects are still invisible, and illusions are still visible as what they seem to be. Likewise, darkvision subjects a creature to gaze attacks normally. The presence of light does not spoil darkvision.
>
> Deaf (Ex)  Akatas cannot hear. They are immune to spells and effects that rely >on hearing to function, but they also cannot make Perception checks to listen.
>
> Hibernation (Ex)  Akatas can enter a state of hibernation for an indefinite period of time when food is scarce. When an akata wishes to enter hibernation, it seeks out a den and surrounds itself in a layer of fibrous material excreted from its mouth - these fibers quickly harden into a dense, almost metallic cocoon. While hibernating, an akata does not need to eat or drink. The cocoon has hardness 10 and 60 hit points, and is immune to fire and bludgeoning (including falling) damage. As long as the cocoon remains intact, the akata within remains unharmed. The akata remains in a state of hibernation until it senses another living creature within 10 feet or is exposed to extreme heat, at which point it claws its way to freedom in 1d4 minutes as its cocoon degrades to fragments of strange metal.
>
> Immunity to Cold (Ex)  You never take cold damage.
>
> Immunity to Disease (Ex)  You are never subject to disease effects.
>
> Immunity to Poison (Ex)  You never take poison damage.
>
> No Breath (Ex)  A creature with this ability does not breathe, and is immune to effects that require breathing (such as inhaled poison). This does not give immunity to cloud or gas attacks that do not require breathing.
>
> Resistance to Fire (Ex)  You may ignore 30 points of Fire damage each time you take fire damage.
>
> Scent (Ex)  You can detect approaching enemies, sniff out hidden foes, and track by sense of smell. You can identify familiar odors just as humans do familiar sights. You can detect opponents within 30 feet by sense of smell. If the opponent is upwind, the range increases to 60 feet; if downwind, it drops to 15 feet. Strong scents, such as smoke or rotting garbage, can be detected at twice the ranges noted above. Overpowering scents, such as skunk musk or troglodyte stench, can be detected at triple normal range. When you detect a scent, the exact location of the source is not revealed--only its presence somewhere within range. You can take a move action to note the direction of the scent. When you are within 5 feet of the source, you pinpoint the source's location. You can follow tracks by smell, making a Wisdom (or Survival) check to find or follow a track. The typical DC for a fresh trail is 10 (no matter what kind of surface holds the scent). This DC increases or decreases depending on how strong the quarry's odor is, the number of creatures, and the age of the trail. For each hour that the trail is cold, the DC increases by 2. The ability otherwise follows the rules for the Survival skill. When tracking by scent you ignore the effects of surface conditions and poor visibility.
>
> Void Bite (Ex)  Akatas hold hundreds of invisibly small larval young within their mouths, spreading these parasitic creatures to hosts through their bite. Only humanoids make suitable hosts for akata young - all other creature types are immune to this parasitic infection. The disease itself is known as void death. Disease: Void Death: Bite - injury; save Fort DC 12; onset 1 hour; frequency 1/day; effect 1d2 Dex and 1d2 Con damage; an infected creature who dies rises as a void zombie 2d4 hours later; cure 2 consecutive saves.
>
> Vulnerable to Salt Water (Ex)  Salt water acts as an extremely strong acid to akatas. A splash of salt water deals 1d6 points of damage to an akata, and full immersion in salt water deals 4d6 points of damage per round.

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth giving the Homebrewery a look

http://homebrewery.naturalcrit.com/

This has default stat block insert at one of the options and as it's all HTML it's actually pretty easy to adjust them to your particular game if it has different stat names or skills.

Once you have it set up you can export as PDF or copy a image into another format. It may not be ideal for using in word as you can't get the styles to copy across and keep the text editbale - but on the other hand - the homebrewery may replace the need for Word entirely if it does all the things you need?

Answer (score -4):

In an attempt to make this as universal as possible. I would use the tools nearly everyone has (Excel & Word) rather simply.

First thing to do is to setup a default Excel Book (RPGBlockMaker.xlsx perhaps?). The Excel sheet should look like this or whatever additional stats you may have.

[image]

Turn the "Mod" (C) column into a formula that will tell you your stats. In Pathfinder/DND the formula is "=FLOOR((**B2**-10)/2,1)" -> Note that **B2** will represent your cell containing the score value.

Now all you have to do in the future is to simply change score of whatever the abilities should be for any given stat block.

Now that you have your stat block, I want you to highlight it and copy like so
[image]

And just paste that into WORD with **special formatting** and the results are below. Once you setup the Excel sheet correctly, this should be a cakewalk when using the proper formula
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I think this answer is attracting downvotes because the question asked about formatting a proper Pathfinder stat block, and not any way to format the stats.